# Developing Automatic selection of scanner using TWAIN

Tags: c++, twain

I have developed a code to interact with Flatbed and Automatic Document Feeder type of scanner in twain using c++. Now i want to include a new functionality in my code which will be a automatic function means it by default scan from ADF scanner but if there is no document in ADF scanner it automatically take input from flatbed part. Please suggest me some CAPABILITY function of twain or sample code or some important link to introduce this new functionality in my code.

Comment: what have you found or tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To scan from auto feeder of a scanner, you can use the CAP_FEEDERENABLED capability.

To check if there are documents available in the feeder, you can:

CAP_PAPERDETECTABLE - determine if the Source can tell that documents are loaded.
Set the TW_CAPABILITY.Cap field to CAP_FEEDERLOADED to check if there are documents loaded.

You can refer to the [TWAIN specification](http://www.twain.org/component/attachments/download/3579.html) for more details.